# How to detect whether Windows is shutting down or restarting

Tags: c++, winapi, api, shutdown, restart

I know that when Windows is shutting down, it sends a [WM_QUERYENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376890(VS.85).aspx) message to each application. This makes it easy to detect when Windows is shutting down. However, is it possible to know if the computer going to power-off or is it going to restart after Windows has shutdown.

I am not particularly hopeful, considering the documentation at MSDN has this to say about `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`: "...it is not possible to determine which event is occurring," but the cumulative cleverness of stackoverflow never ceases to amaze me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [here](http://www.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?ARCHIVE=true&TOPIC_ID=3397):

> You can read the DWORD value from
>   "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shutdown
>   Setting" to determine what the user
>   last selected from the Shut Down
>   dialog.

A bit of a roundabout solution, but it should do the trick.

Comment: That is of course assuming that the system is now shutting down because the current user initiated it, and did so in Explorer. If this is a programmatic shutdown, shutdown from another app, or shutdown by another user, you'd get the reason for a previous shutdown.

Comment: -1 Because the answer is incomplete and specific to Windows Explorer. It also appears to be **removed** in Windows 7.

Comment: It works well under WindowsXP but not under Windows7

Answer (score 10):

In Windows 7 (and probably also in Vista / 8 / Server) you could use the system events to track whether Windows is shutting down (and powering off the computer) or just restarting. Every time a shutdown/reboot is initiated (by any means - clicking the button in Start menu, or programmatically), Windows 7 writes one or two events in the System log, source USER32, event ID 1074. You can see these events recorded if you open the Event Viewer from Administrative Tools (filter the System log to see only ID 1074). The description (message) of these events contains the shutdown type. So you could parse the description of the most recent event of this type (after the shutdown was initiated), looking for the necessary word (shutdown, reboot/restart).

I didn't try to see the shutdown type written in the event when using the power button to gracefully shutdown Windows (I usually disable this function), but some site suggests that it states a "power off" type instead of "shutdown" - so check it out, if you need to be sure. Or simply look for a "reboot" type - if it's not found, then a "shutdown" type is assumed.

In Windows XP, from my experience, an event 1074 is recorded only if the shutdown/reboot is done programmatically (e.g. during a program install or using the shutdown.exe utility). So it does not register the shutdowns initiated from the shell (Explorer), but perhaps you could combine this method with reading the value from registry as proposed in another answer. Also, keep in mind that in WinXP the message of event 1074 contains the word "restart" no matter what the real type of shutdown is, so you should look at the "Shutdown Type:" field, which will state either "shutdown" or "reboot".

Related to this, an event ID 1073 is recorded whenever Windows fails to shutdown/reboot for some reason (e.g. if an application doesn't allow to shutdown as a response to WM_QUERYENDSESSION). In that case the message will also contain words as "shutdown", "reboot" or "power off" - in WinXP. For Win7 this type of event is less useful in our case, since it won't make any difference between shutdown and reboot. But for WinXP - if you only need to intercept the shutdown/reboot, perform some actions, then continue the corresponding shutdown or reboot process - it should work as expected.

Comment: It is important to note that EventLog shows localized messages so keywords like "shutdown" or "reboot" will be different depending on operating system localization.

Answer (score 5):

A trick that usually works is to trap `WM_ENDSESSION` and log it. Now keep track of the time. If the system comes back up within a reasonable peroid (say 5 minutes). Then that was a reboot, not a shutdown.

**Idea**: If the system comes back up within 5 minutes, does it *really* matter if the user clicked 'shutdown' or 'reboot'?

If you really need to detect a shutdown (and the only reason I think you'd need to do this is if you're depending upon an obscure behavioral software difference between a shutdown vs a reboot) you could investigate `API hooking` of `ExitWindowsEx` and related functions but I don't recommend this approach. Rethink if you really need to detect this directly.

Comment: +1 for the API hooking suggestion. Time checking suggestion is pure guesswork.

Comment: @Joe, With modern ACPI power management: Sleep, Hibernate, Wake On LAN, and so on. The definition of reboot (or warm boot) is becoming hard to define. What most people mean by reboot (or close enough) is that the system was not in a normal state for a very *short period* of time.

Answer (score 2):

Possible experimental solution for Windows7 could be the following. (I'm not sure if this works well with other localizations, therefore I would call it a workaround)

```
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;

namespace MyApp
{
public class RestartDetector : IDisposable
{
    public delegate void OnShutdownRequsted(bool restart);
    public OnShutdownRequsted onShutdownRequsted;

    private EventLogWatcher watcher = null;

    public RestartDetector()
    {
        try
        {
            EventLogQuery subscriptionQuery = new EventLogQuery(
                "System", PathType.LogName, "*[System[Provider[@Name='USER32'] and (EventID=1074)]]");

            watcher = new EventLogWatcher(subscriptionQuery);

            // Make the watcher listen to the EventRecordWritten
            // events.  When this event happens, the callback method
            // (EventLogEventRead) is called.
            watcher.EventRecordWritten +=
                new EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(
                    EventLogEventRead);

            // Activate the subscription
            watcher.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (EventLogReadingException e)
        {
        }
    }

    public void EventLogEventRead(object obj, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs arg)
    {
        bool restart = false;
        try
        {
            // Make sure there was no error reading the event.
            if (arg.EventRecord != null)
            {
                String[] xPathRefs = new String[1];
                xPathRefs[0] = "Event/EventData/Data";
                IEnumerable<String> xPathEnum = xPathRefs;

                EventLogPropertySelector logPropertyContext = new EventLogPropertySelector(xPathEnum);
                IList<object> logEventProps = ((EventLogRecord)arg.EventRecord).GetPropertyValues(logPropertyContext);

                string[] eventData = (string[])logEventProps[0];

                foreach (string attribute in eventData)
                {
                    if (attribute.Contains("restart")) { restart = true; break; }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (onShutdownRequsted != null) { onShutdownRequsted(restart); }
        }   
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Stop listening to events
        if (watcher != null)
        {
            watcher.Enabled = false;
            watcher.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
}
```

The following is an example of XML which is written to the event log when a PC is restarted:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="USER32" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="32768">1074</EventID> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-12-15T11:10:43.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>90416</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>WIN7PC</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1257383181-1549154685-2724014583-1000" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>C:\Windows\system32\winlogon.exe (WIN7PC)</Data> 
  <Data>WIN7PC</Data> 
  <Data>No title for this reason could be found</Data> 
  <Data>0x500ff</Data> 
  <Data>restart</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>WIN7PC\WIN7PCUser</Data> 
 <Binary>FF00050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Comment: The XPath query just returned the first DATA entry for me which was a string and not even a string array. Simplified my code like this and works nicely now: 
if (arg.EventRecord != null)
{         
  foreach (EventProperty x  in ((EventLogRecord)arg.EventRecord).Properties)
  {
    if (x.Value.Equals("restart")) { restart = true; break; }
  }
}