# Tell reboot from shutdown on Windows Server 2008

Tags: python, windows, winapi, windows-server-2008, pywin32

As per MSDN, it is not possible to determine, whether reboot or
shutdown occurred using WM_ENDSESSION Message.

I've found [the only way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981306) to do this, but it's quite ugly and works only
for Windows 2000 Server, not for 2008 Server.

The reason I'm asking is that I'm in process of porting Linux daemon
to Windows as System Service. This daemon acts differently on reboot
and system shutdown events.

I am also using python with pywin32 in project if it somehow helps to answer.

Comment: In what way does the daemon act differently in those two scenarios?  Form the perspective of your daemon, how is a shutdown + startup different than a reboot?

Answer (score 0):

You need to investigate using HookAPI (SetWindowsHookEx?) to capture all ExitWindowsEx calls before they happen.

Links that may help:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=KMKiMfBD
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Paladin.aspx