# In C# , How to find whether windows Re-Starting?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect whether Windows is shutting down or restarting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981306/how-to-detect-whether-windows-is-shutting-down-or-restarting)

In c# I am able to find only whether windows is logging off or getting shutdown using below code.

```
SystemEvents.SessionEnding += new SessionEndingEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnding);

static void SystemEvents_SessionEnding(object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (e.Reason)
        {
            case SessionEndReasons.Logoff:
                break;
            case SessionEndReasons.SystemShutdown:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

But I want to know how to capture windows re-start event in c#.?

Comment: I am curious: Why whould that be from interest for a programm to know if a computer is shutdown or rebooted. How would that affect your programm? Even if I choose reboot, I can still cancel the process before windows is loading by just powering of the machine.

Comment: Richards , Reading registry and find out whether windows is restarting is look like some work around. I feel there should be some win32 events to find out this. More over I logged in windows using limited user. So I can't read registry settings.

Comment: SchlaWiener, In my App, I don't want the user to shutdown, But he should be able to re-start, or logoff the machine.

Comment: You would do better to do this by policy rather than by your application.

Comment: What's stopping the user from force-quitting your application? I'd go with a more system-managerial process (such as BugFinder's suggestion to use policies).

Comment: So the Answer is , there is no Windows Event to find machine is going to re-started.