# Is there a way to programmatically receive if Windows is shutting down or restarting?

Tags: c++, windows

Is there a way to capture if Windows shutting down, or it is restarting? For shutdown, i found some solutions, but not for restart. For me it would be important to be able to determine if Windows is restarting, or just shutting down.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981306/how-to-detect-whether-windows-is-shutting-down-or-restarting

Comment: @Sean: I found that, but my problem is with this solution, what is described there. What happenes for example if i make an appplication and it will restart Windows? Then the user didn't chose to restart the system, so i can't read the registry value.

Comment: OK. Why is it imporant to know the difference between a shutdown and a restart. After all, if the user shuts down and then powers back up straight away it's basically the same thing.

Comment: In my case unfortunately it is not. It is very complicated why, but i need to know the difference :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the Windows last reboot reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140092/how-can-i-get-the-windows-last-reboot-reason)

Comment: You **can't** know this, really. Windows **may** think it will restart, but it's not uncommon to turn a machine off when it's finished its shutdown in preparation for a restart. And obviously, since the machine at that point is shut down, you can't detect that.

Comment: You get a *little* bit of info from the WM_QUERYENDSESSION notification.  Windows strongly avoids telling you too much about the shutdown reason, it cannot guarantee that (say) a sleep or hibernate is going to allow the OS to restart from the saved state.  It isn't around to ensure that a restart will actually happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to detect whether it is shutting down and also there is a way to detect when it starts up.

So, you can note the time [when it is shutting down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981306/how-to-detect-whether-windows-is-shutting-down-or-restarting). Note the time when it is starting by running an exe at startup (add your exe here in registry: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce).

If the time difference is very less then you can treat it as a 'Restart'.

Also you can use [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) api for exact events.